# How to Set SonarQube Leak period by branch

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

I have configured the SonarQube to make runs automatically in the past 2 months using maven and jacoco.

The problem is that we need to start using branch scans. I saw that if I try to set the scan to a different project key I get an error message that the module already belongs to a different project.

I moved to using sonar.branch parameter which works fine but then for some reason my Leak Period parameter is not working properly and I can't get any data on new code.

Any idea why the Leak Period has stopped working when using sonar.branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from the description is :

- you are trying to analysis different branches.
- In order to get rid of this error (module already belongs to a different project) , you are using sonar.branch property.

When using sonar.branch property, what it actually does is, it append this value to the project Key mentioned (may be default) and hence globalProjectKey becomes : projectKey:BranchKey ,along with this each module key is also appended by branch key. That's why you don't see the above error.

However, as the dashboard is also created new due to different global project key, I don't think that leak period should work.

It treats the two sets of code differently.